# Wash Sale Matching after selling for profit

Tags: united-states, taxes, wash-sale

day 1, I buy 200 shares  @ $2  (lot A)

day 20 I buy 100 shares  @ $2  (lot B)

day 21 I sell 100 shares @ $3  (selling lot B)

day 40 I sell 100 shares @ $1  (selling lot A)

Is the last sale a wash sale?

Comment: Why are there so many wash sale questions?  What blog is talking about wash sales right now?

Comment: @quid It's tax time in the U.S. Possibly people are getting hit with a wash-sale tax rate and they're learning of its existence for the first time.

Comment: How is this different from [Wash sale repetition through chaining](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/93166/wash-sale-repetition-through-chaining) ? Given the way these questions a worded, Do you really have a potential wash sale?

Comment: Chances are, people are getting their 8949 statements from their broker(s), seeing the "W" code for wash sale and they are wondering, WTH are these adjustments that reduce the loss incurred and can't be deducted ???  Welcome to the world of the IRS.

Comment: @BobBaerker - I know you are replying to quid. No problem. My issue is these two questions don't reflect real examples. The other OP got irate when I suggested that once 30 days passed, the wash issue was moot.

Comment: At this point I suspect we're unpaid consultants to some tax optimization software project.

Comment: well, still i got two answers one saying wash, the other saying not yet.

Comment: I deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

> day 1, I buy 200 shares @ $2 (lot A)
>
> day 20 I buy 100 shares @ $2 (lot B)
>
> day 21 I sell 100 shares @ $3 (selling lot B)
>
> day 40 I sell 100 shares @ $1 (selling lot A)

On day 21, you sold 100 shares from Lot B, at a profit, so Lot B is gone.

On day 40, the 100 shares sold at $1, Lot A shares, are sold at a loss, therefore, Wash becomes an issue if you buy replacement shares on or before day 70.

Comment: Hmmm, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wash_sale) sale is

> a sale of a security (stocks, bonds, options) at a loss and repurchase of the same or substantially identical security shortly before or after

According to this definition, the following scenario includes a wash sale:

1. day 1,  I buy 200 shares @ $2 (lot A)
2. day 40, I sell 100 shares @ $1 (lot A)
3. day 41, I buy 100 shares @ $1 (lot A)